# Is it possible to auto increment float in Apache Derby?

Tags: sql, derby, auto-increment

I'm looking to create two similar tables, both of which need an auto-increment function. It appears that on `Apache Derby`, you can only increment whole numbers like:

```
Create Table Mapping
(
id Integer PRIMARY KEY GENERATED ALWAYS AS IDENTITY (START WITH 1, INCREMENT BY 1),
uname VARCHAR(30) NOT NULL
);
```

which runs successfully. I want to achieve this:

```
Create Table GMapping
(
gid Float PRIMARY KEY GENERATED ALWAYS AS IDENTITY (START WITH 1.00001, INCREMENT BY .00001),
gname VARCHAR(30) NOT NULL
);
```

which throws an error that `1.00001` and `.00001` are not valid integer literals.

Is there a way to achieve this? If not that, could I possibly use auto increment for anything but `Integer`, `SMALLINT`, which doesn't need me to specify a whole number?

Comment: I've figured a way to achieve two different ranges, that is, I used negative integers for the second range. But I'd still like if someone could answer this :)